# Growing number of a file title

Tags: c#, foreach

I have 13 .srt files. Each of them have in title *"2x--"* the "--" is the number of episode subtitle. I have a code that scores all of the information about each .srt file (used foreach) but I want to set each of the .srt file to a adequate movie file(by just changing the name of .srt file to a movie name). For example: I've got a folder where is a one .srt file and one .mp4 file. The .srt file is called: Example - 2x01(.srt) and the movie file is called Example.S01E01(.mp4). So I want to make my app detect the number *"2x--"* (after 2x) and find an adequate movie (in this case it will be numbers after "E" *"S01E--"*) I hope you understood my question, I have no idea how can I track it...

[This is how I see it. [IMAGE]](http://puu.sh/jKubX/e0ef1091fb.jpg)

Comment: It's clear but Stack Overflow isn't place for broad vague questions asking for *ideas*. See also [help]

Comment: So better if I would be a leecher who wants a ready-to-paste code?

Comment: Of course NOT but it doesn't make *this* question more on topic. Try something, even regex (for example) and if you can't make it work then come back with code and a failed attempt...

Comment: Alright, I will try it. You could write that in the first comment instead of being rough.

Comment: I'm not native speaker, sorry if my comment was too rough!

Answer (score 1):

You're probably talking about regular expressions, as you subtitle file name does have a common pattern like `"<title> - 2X<episode>.srt"` and you want do convert it to another pattern, `"<title>.S01E<episode>.mp4"`

The code below does the trick. The `title` group contains any characters *until* it finds a sequence of `- 2x` then it get the `episode` group as one or more numbers.

```
foreach (var fullPath in Directory.GetFiles("*.srt"))
{
    // "Example - 2x01.srt"
    var subtitle = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
    var match = Regex.Match(subtitle, @"(?<title>.*?) - 2x(?<episode>\d+)\.");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        // "Example.S01E01.mp4"
        var movie = String.Format("{0}.S01E{1}.mp4", 
            match.Groups["title"].Value,
            match.Groups["episode"].Value);
        Console.WriteLine(movie);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for an reply, it works. But what can I do when the subtitle names are different? For example, one is "Example - 2x01.srt" and one is "Example - 2x01 - Cool.HDTV.ASAP.en.srt" I cannot manage to do it in regex.